# Get boolean from database using Android and SQLite

Tags: java, android, sqlite, boolean

How can I obtain the value of a boolean field in an [SQLite](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQLite) database on Android?

I usually use `getString()`, `getInt()`, etc. to get the values of my fields, but there does not seem to be a `getBoolean()` method.

Answer (score 363, accepted):

It is:

```
boolean value = cursor.getInt(boolean_column_index) > 0;
```

Comment: cursor.getInt(boolean_column_index) != 0

is more standard C.

Comment: @Buttink `>0` is shorter in bytes though :P

Comment: stackoverflow 不爱不行

Comment: For an optional (nullable) Boolean, see answer below: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65828389/7493938

Answer (score 46):

There is no bool data type in SQLite. Use an int that you fix to 0 or 1 to achieve that effect. See the [datatypes reference](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html) on [SQLite 3.0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQLite#History).

Answer (score 24):

```
boolean value = (cursor.getInt(boolean_column_index) == 1);
```

Comment: Even though not exactly corresponding to this question (Alex's is the closest), it's an excellent answer, and I'll use this.

Answer (score 11):

Most of the answers here can result in NumberFormatExceptions or "operator is undefined for the types null, int" if the column you stored the int in was allowed to also hold null.
The decent way to do this would be to use

```
Boolean.parseBoolean(cursor.getString(booleanColumnIndex));`
```

though you are now limited to storing the strings "true" and "false" rather than 0 or 1.

Comment: This does not work. Boolean.parseBoolean takes "true" or "false" strings. If you have stored your boolean as 0 or 1 you will always get false.

Comment: If what Gober says is true, then this answer deserves to be downvoted

Comment: Ah, he's right. I think the clarity of the result outweighs having to store the strings.

Comment: @ShervinAsgari in the other answer if you store your boolean as true or false it will always get false. So it should be downvoted too with your logic.

Answer (score 6):

You can also use

```
boolean value =cursor.getString(boolean_column_index).equals("True");
```

Comment: equals() not contains

Answer (score 6):

An implementation found at [Ormlite Cursor](http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-android/com/j256/ormlite/android/AndroidDatabaseResults.html#getBoolean%28int%29) also checks for Null which none of the other answers do.

```
   public boolean getBoolean(int columnIndex) {
        if (cursor.isNull(columnIndex) || cursor.getShort(columnIndex) == 0) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

`boolean` datatype is not available in `Cursor`.

you will get the result in an `int`, so you need to convert that `int` value to a `boolean`.

You can either use

```
boolean b = cursor.getInt(boolean_column_index) > 0;
```

or

```
boolean b = (cursor.getInt(boolean_column_index) != 0);
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option

```
boolean value = (cursor.getString(column_index)).equals("1");
```

Answer (score 2):

boolean b = (cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("item")) != 0);

Answer (score 1):

thats what I used:

```
    val work = Work()
    work.id = cursor.getInt(0)
    work.date = cursor.getString(1)
    work.work_value = cursor.getFloat(2)
    work.place = cursor.getString(3)
    work.wind = cursor.getFloat(4)
    work.isCompetition = cursor.getInt(5) > 0
    return work
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, that's very simple:

```
public boolean getBooleanState(SQLiteDatabase db){
    boolean result = false;
    try{
        String QUERY = "SELECT " + BOOLEAN_DATA + " FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE " + ID + " = 1";
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(QUERY, null);
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()){
            if(cursor.getString(0).equalsIgnoreCase("1")){
                result = true;
            }
        }
        c.close();
    }catch(Exception ee){
        Log.e(TAG, "err getBooleanState: " + TABLE_NAME );
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For an optional (nullable) Boolean stored as `INTEGER`, you can create a Kotlin extension:

```
fun Cursor.getBoolean(columnIndex: Int): Boolean? {
    return if (isNull(columnIndex))
        null
    else 
        getInt(columnIndex) != 0
}
```

and use it like this:

```
val value: Boolean? = cursor.getBoolean(boolean_column_index)
```

Answer (score -1):

I face the same thing in kotlin.
There was the value "true/false" in the database
and I access it with this code:

```
cursor.getString(4).toBoolean()
```

//first as a string then converting them to boolean