# Working with boolean values in an SQLite database

Tags: android, database, sqlite, relational-database, android-sqlite

I read that SQLite databases support a `boolean` value. Here's my query to create the table:

```
private static final String CREATE_TABLE_PROMEMORIE_RSI = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXIXSTS "
            + promemorieRSI.PROMEMORIE_RSI_TABLE + " ("
            + promemorieRSI.ID + " integer primary key autoincrement, "
            + promemorieRSI.GIORNO + " integer, "
            + promemorieRSI.MESE + " integer, "
            + promemorieRSI.ANNO + " integer, "
            + promemorieRSI.NOT_RIP_RSI + " boolean, "
            + promemorieRSI.RIP_VAL_RSI + " integer, "
            + promemorieRSI.UNIT_RIP_VAL_RSI + " text, "
            + promemorieRSI.NOT_FISSA_RSI + " boolean, "
            + promemorieRSI.ETICHETTA_RSI + " text, "
            + promemorieRSI.REQUEST_CODE_RSI + " integer);";
```

As you can see, I set the `not_rip_rsi` and `not_fissa_rsi` columns to be of `boolean` values. I read that the database stores the `true` and `false` values as, respectively, `1` and `0` integer values, but now I can't understand this:

- When I add a record to the database, what value should I use for these columns?

For better explanation, here's my insert method:

```
public void inserisciPromemoriaRSI(Integer giorno, Integer mese, Integer anno, Boolean not_rip, Integer rip_val, String unit_rip_val, Boolean not_fissa, String etichetta, Integer request_code){
        ContentValues val = new ContentValues();
        val.put(promemorieRSI.GIORNO, giorno);
        val.put(promemorieRSI.MESE, mese);
        val.put(promemorieRSI.ANNO, anno);
        val.put(promemorieRSI.NOT_RIP_RSI, not_rip);
        val.put(promemorieRSI.RIP_VAL_RSI, rip_val);
        val.put(promemorieRSI.UNIT_RIP_VAL_RSI, unit_rip_val);
        val.put(promemorieRSI.NOT_FISSA_RSI, not_fissa);
        val.put(promemorieRSI.ETICHETTA_RSI, etichetta);
        val.put(promemorieRSI.REQUEST_CODE_RSI, request_code);
        mDb.insert(promemorieRSI.PROMEMORIE_RSI_TABLE, null, val);
    }
```

As you can see, to add the record I use a `boolean` value for these columns. Even if I set the value of the entries of those columns to be of type `boolean`, when I add a record, should I use an integer value of `1` or `0`  instead of a `boolean` value, or will the database automatically store `true` as `1` and `false` as 0? Will I have to use a `cursor.getInt(column_index) == 1` to get the boolean value? Am I making a mistake in my code? If so, how do I solve this problem. Any suggestions?

Comment: What is the language of your code? PS Have you googled this yet?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Store boolean value in SQLite](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/843780/store-boolean-value-in-sqlite)

Comment: Already saw questions about this argument, but couldn't answer to my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `boolean` doesn't exists in SQLite. Instead, you store the `boolean` value in the database as an `INTEGER` in SQLite. The values that you can use are `0` for `false` and `1` for `true`. When you go and select the `INTEGER` from the database, to change it to a `boolean`, you use:

```
boolean isTrue = cursor.getInt(columnNo) > 0;
```

If you want a value of `false`, then:

```
boolean isFalse = cursor.getInt(columnNo) < 1;
```

Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/843780/store-boolean-value-in-sqlite) post and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4088080/get-boolean-from-database-using-android-and-sqlite) post for further information.

Comment: I've already seen those posts, but I can't understand at all.. If I set the value of those columns to be of type `boolean` , when I insert a record have I to pass an `integer` value (`1` or `0`) or a `boolean`?

Comment: You create the columns in your table to be of type `INTEGER` and pass a value of `1` or `0`. `boolean`s don't exists in SQLite and are stored as integers.

Comment: Let me see if I understood.. In the query to make the table I **must** change the `boolean` type to `integer` (Is the same if upcased or not, right?), but I **can** pass a value of `boolean` type on the insert method and the database will **_automatically_** convert it to an `integer` (`0` or `1`)(And so I would only have to change the query to make the table)

Comment: Almost right. You must pass an `integer`, either `0` for `false` or `1` for `true`. If you pass a `boolean`, you app might crash.The data type `boolean` doesn't exists in SQLite.

Comment: Thank you very much :) <br/> I have to make a big change to my reminder-app.. It's hard coding if your knowledge is very basic, but I like it

Comment: this would unnecessarily increase the size of db

Comment: +10101010 Yeah, I agree. I don't think SQLite has a BIT data type like MSSQL does